# Inheritance with plain old data structs

Tags: go, oop, inheritance

Interfaces are defined by their functionality and not by the data they contain. This, I find, makes mimicking C++ style inheritance difficult for Plain Old Data (POD) classes. The only solution I can think of is to implement a method that does nothing for all struct that implement the interface. Consider the below example with "fooSignatureMove"

```
package main

type foo interface{
   // fooSignatureMove does nothing but allow to mimick inheritence
   fooSignatureMove()
}

type A struct{}
type B struct{}
type C struct{}

func (*A) fooSignatureMove(){}
func (*B) fooSignatureMove(){}


func main(){
  arr := make([]foo, 2)
  arr[0] = &A{}
  arr[1] = &B{}
  arr[2] = &C{} // I do not want this to compile
}
```

Is this good practice?

Comment: Is something like this what you are asking about, see [ast.Expr](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/ast/ast.go#L39-L42) and the [implementations](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/ast/ast.go#L550-L576)? I don't know whether I would classify it as good practice, but it's definitely common in the std lib and I've used it many times myself.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, exactly! So, yes you just proved that is the way to go around inheritance of POD objects in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mkopriva explained in a comment, this pattern is indeed quite common in the standard library, so it is probably the way to go. See for example [ast.Expr](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/ast/ast.go#L39-L42) and [exprNode](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/ast/ast.go#L550-L576)